# Type handleChange is not assignable to type

Tags: javascript, material-ui, webstorm, onchange

I'm using `MaterialUI` to generate a `TabList`. I created the handler:

```js
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
}
```

and am calling it here:

```html
<TabList aria-label={"toggle product"} onChange={handleChange} textColor={colors.grey[100]}>
     <Tab label={"REVENUE"} value={"revenue"}/>
     <Tab label={"EPS"} value={"eps"} />
</TabList>
```

However, my IDE (WebStorm) is raising this inspection error:

> Type handleChange is not assignable to type `{(event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: any): void, (event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: any): void, (event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: any): void}`

Am I calling the function in correctly?

Comment: Please show the full error message

Comment: `const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: any)`